# Extract out letters between 2nd period and 3rd period in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have this vector called `Identifier`:

```
c("NC.1.OA", "NC.1.OA.0", "NC.1.OA.1", "NC.1.OA.1.a", "NC.1.OA.1.b", 
"NC.1.OA.1.c", "NC.1.OA.2", "NC.1.OA.2.0", "NC.1.OA.3", "NC.1.OA.4"
)
```

I'd like to extract out the `OA`

I've tried:

```
gsub(".*\\.(.*)\\..*", "\\1", Identifier)
```

Basically, I'd like to extract out the text between the second and the third periods. If there are only two periods (`NC.1.OA`), I'd like to extract out everything after the second period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat (non-periods, followed by a period) twice, then capture non-periods, and the substring you want is in that captured group:

```
Identifier = c("NC.1.OA", "NC.1.OA.0", "NC.1.OA.1", "NC.1.OA.1.a", "NC.1.OA.1.b", 
"NC.1.OA.1.c", "NC.1.OA.2", "NC.1.OA.2.0", "NC.1.OA.3", "NC.1.OA.4"
)
gsub("(?:[^.]+\\.){2}([^.]+).*", "\\1", Identifier)
```

Output:

```
[1] "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA"
```

To elaborate, `(?:[^.]+\\.)` is a group which matches non-period characters and then a single period. The `{2}` after the group means that the preceding token (the group) is repeated twice - that is, "non-periods, followed by a period, followed by non-periods, followed by a period.". Then, the final `([^.]+)` matches as many non-period characters as it can past the second period, thereby matching non-periods between the second period and the third period (or the end of the string).

Comment: `"\\1"` what does this part do? I don't see this part in the explanation

Comment: It does the exact same thing it does in the code that you wrote originally - it echos what was captured in the first captured group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to `sub` using `strsplit` with `apply`:

```
sapply(Identifier, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\\."))[3])

NC.1.OA   NC.1.OA.0   NC.1.OA.1 NC.1.OA.1.a NC.1.OA.1.b NC.1.OA.1.c 
    "OA"        "OA"        "OA"        "OA"        "OA"        "OA" 
NC.1.OA.2 NC.1.OA.2.0   NC.1.OA.3   NC.1.OA.4 
    "OA"        "OA"        "OA"        "OA"
```

Comment: What does the `[3]` do?

Comment: Third element after splitting on dot.

Answer (score 0):

We could try `stringr` too:

```
Identifier = c("NC.1.OA", "NC.1.OA.0", "NC.1.OA.1", "NC.1.OA.1.a", "NC.1.OA.1.b", 
               "NC.1.OA.1.c", "NC.1.OA.2", "NC.1.OA.2.0", "NC.1.OA.3", "NC.1.OA.4"
)
library(stringr)
str_extract(Identifier, ".OA.")
# [1] NA     ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA." ".OA."
str_extract(Identifier, "OA")
# [1] "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA"
gsub('\\.', '', str_extract(Identifier, ".OA.?"))
# [1] "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regmatches(Identifier, gregexpr("OA", Identifier))
```

wrap `?unlist` if you need a vector

```
unlist(
    regmatches(Identifier, gregexpr("OA", Identifier))
)
# [1] "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA" "OA"
```